# Android: App shortcut has to be recreated after update

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

A weird thing is happening:
I've published an update to google play. When users download the update the existing home screen shortcut disappears and the have to recreate it or on other devices, the shortcut stays on the homescreen, but when they press it, it says the refering app isn't there and then they have to delete that shortcut and recreate it.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you move your launcher Activity (By moving it to an other package: from com.example to com.example.activity)?

Comment: @Ahmad Well I've chosen another launcher activity. You think that could be it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Well I've chosen another launcher activity.

This is why it isn't working anymore. The shortcut references a launcher Activity and since you changed it, the shortcut won't work anymore.

Comment: I think this is quite inconvenient for the user. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @alex yes, use an activity alias: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html

Comment: How about having 2 activities with MAIN/Launcher intents?

Comment: @AlexVPerl sorry didn't quite get your question, what about them?